# What are the performance implications of isolating a core vs PREEMPT_RT?

Tags: raspberry-pi, real-time

I try to figure out what the differences between several real time systems are.

So far I've tried to use the PREEMPT_RT patch and to isolate a core and reserve it for the RT application.

So far I've tested using:

```
    taskset -c 3 cyclictest -m -t1 -p 80 -n -i 500 -l 100000
    hackbench -l 100000
    cat /dev/zero > /dev/null
    cat /dev/zero > /dev/null
    cat /dev/zero > /dev/null
```

My testsetup runs on an raspberry pi 3. But I'm interested in the general picutre, not the specific hardware.

Using PRREMPT_RT gives reaction times up to 150 µs, while isolating a core gives reaction times below 50µs.
So isolating a core seems to work a lot better, than PRREMPT_RT.

Which testcases should be added to either verify my results or turn the table in favor for PREEMPT_RT?

Which advantages and disadvantags do both of these approaches offer?

Comment: There are vendors that isolate cores in their Linux appliances, like Meru. I also isolate a CPU for a frontend for a very busy site whose server was constantly going berserk, and it worked pretty well. Unfortunately, my experience of running RT kernels should be outdated by now.